# Setting duration is not working in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, duration

Have problem with creating video from 50 png files in ffmpeg in shell.
Setting duration `-t 5` and fps `-r 10`

`ffmpeg -i image%d.png -y -pix_fmt yuv444p -r 10 -t 5 -s 1920:1080 out.mp4`

Final duration is 2 seconds and fps is 25.

How to set it correctly?

I'm running at elementaryOS, ffmpeg version 0.8.10-4

Thanks

Comment: The solution is

`ffmpeg -r 10 -i image%d.png -y -pix_fmt yuv444p -t 5  -s 1920:1080 out.mp4`

Comment: You can provide and accept your own answers to your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is
`ffmpeg -r 10 -i image%d.png -y -pix_fmt yuv444p -t 5  -s 1920:1080 out.mp4`

Need to set fps `-r` before input data.